# feedback form for WP7 app

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, feedback

How would I go about implementing a feedback function on a windows phone 7 app?  I've considered creating a form that sends an email with the data to an address I own, but I wonder if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally think the simplest and best solution is to use [EmailComposeTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.emailcomposetask%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) to send the feedback via email.

You could either just put some questions/suggested text in the `Body` - or you could fill the `Body` in with some information from a SL form.

One of the advantages of the EmailComposeTask is you will definitely get their email address to reply to. Another advantage is that the feedback will work even when there isn't currently a network connection - it'll just get added to the outbox for later processing.

Comment: a lot simpler to implement than the webservice solution, and most apps probably wouldn't need the benefits that the webservice would bring.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would create a webservice that can receive that data. It could be useful in case you have a backend system that can make some data statistics.

You can refer to that post that contains some code about data sending to a web service: [WP7 app never exits BeginGetResponse and goes into the callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964616/wp7-app-never-exits-begingetresponse-and-goes-into-the-callback-function/5540193#5540193)

Regards.